# PHPStorm Drush on Vagrant

Tags: drupal-7, vagrant, phpstorm, drush

Is it possible to use the command line tool in PHPstorm to run Drush on a Vagrant box?

If so how do I go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command Line Tool plugin -- no and there is no current plans for that.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-23740 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on decision/progress.

---

But you can use built-in Remote Terminal (over SSH) for that: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Using+the+PhpStorm+built-in+SSH+terminal+and+remote+SSH+external+tools

Comment: Thanks for that, I've been using the SSH terminal so far. Just wondered if there was a way to use the command line tool. I'll keep an eye on that ticket too. Thanks again, Neil.